# ng-cloak does not work with Firefox browser

Tags: angularjs, firefox, ngcloak

Although using ng-cloak,  some bindings are shown with brakets until getting data  at firefox, not other browsers. Which workaround should I do?

Comment: angular doesn't have ng-cloak, you mean angularJs ?

Comment: Yes, I fixed to angularJS. Thanks.

Comment: good to hear hopefully you used `ng-bind` .

Comment: somewhere yes, but somewhere I m using {{}}, also images are shown empty box not  only text things

Comment: From the `ng-cloack` doc on AngularJS: _The directive can be applied to the <body> element, but the preferred usage is to apply multiple ngCloak directives to small portions of the page to permit progressive rendering of the browser view_. This could be the issue

Comment: but why there is no problem at chrome ?@DominicOrim